# не запускается SUT

Tags: java

при запуске sut возникает ошибка:

> Application run failed
>
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:  Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]

что это , с чем связана ошибка?

Comment: Это весь текст ошибки или еще есть?

Comment: Возможно нехватает каких-либо файлов или невозможность их прочитать. См. [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/871996/204920).